# Purescript guard fails with: No type class instance found for Control.MonadZero.MonadZero Identity

Tags: monads, purescript

```
 visitNode :: Castle -> State (Set Castle) Unit
 visitNode c = do
     s <- get
     guard $ not (member c s)
     modify \acc -> insert c s
```

I have some simple code for visiting nodes represented by a custom datatype. I thought MonadZero control functions like guard are supposed to work within all monad structures (such as State in this case). It gives me the error:

`No type class instance was found for 
    Control.MonadZero.MonadZero Identity`

Which I don't understand why MonadZero would not work in this context, but regardless, I attempted to derive the Identity for MonadZero with things like this:

```
 newtype Identity a = Identity a
 derive instance newtypeIdentity :: Newtype (Identity a) _
 derive newtype instance monadZeroIdentity :: MonadZero Identity
```

None of which helped or compiled and I'm fairly sure I misunderstand what is wrong here. How do I use guard or any other monadic checks in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is `when`, not `guard`.

`guard` only works for monads where there is a possibility to *not* produce a result. One example of such monad would be `Maybe`, where `guard` will yield `Nothing` when the condition is false. Another example would be `Array`, where `guard` would yield an empty array when the condition is false. And so on.

In your case, your monad *always* produces a value, so `guard` is really irrelevant there.

Instead, if I understood your logic correctly, what you want to do is produce an effect when a condition is true, and skip producing it when the condition is false. This can be  accomplished via [`when`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/4.1.0/docs/Control.Applicative#v:when) or its evil twin [`unless`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/4.1.0/docs/Control.Applicative#v:unless):

```
visitNode c = do
     s <- get
     unless (member c s) $ 
         modify \_-> insert c s
```

Also note that you're not using the parameter `acc` under `modify`. I've replaced it with an underscore, but really, if you're not using the argument, you don't need `modify`, you need `put`:

```
visitNode c = do
     s <- get
     unless (member c s) $ 
         put (insert c s)
```

But the next thing to notice is that the pattern of `get` and then immediately `put` is exactly what `modify` is for. So in your case, seeing how there are no effects in between `get` and `put`, I would actually put all the logic within `modify` itself:

```
visitNode c = modify \s ->
    if member c s 
        then insert c s 
        else s
```

The less effectful, the better.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This answer tackles issues directly pointed in the question like:
`guard` usage, `MonadPlus` context and `newtype` deriving.

I think that @Fyodor Soikin answer tackles the essence of this problem by replacing `guard` with `when` so this answer can be treated as supplementary material.

I think that if you try something like:

```hs
visitNode :: Castle -> StateT (Set Castle) Maybe Unit
visitNode c = do
  s <- get
  guard $ not (member c s)
  modify \acc -> insert c s
```

it should work because `Maybe` has `MonadZero` instance and [`StateT`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-transformers/4.1.0/docs/Control.Monad.State.Trans#t:StateT) instance depends on this.

Now let's go back and try to resolve some of the problems which you have encountered.

> It gives me the error:
>
> ```
> No type class instance was found for 
>    Control.MonadZero.MonadZero Identity
> ```

This message tells us that `Identity` has no `MonadZero` instance. If we check what is a [`MonadZero`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-control/4.0.0/docs/Control.MonadZero#t:MonadZero) we are going to discover that it is a class which implicates that given type has also `Monad` and `Alternative` instance and which satisfies the `Annihilation` law... [`Identity`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-identity/4.1.0/docs/Data.Identity#t:Identity) has no `Alternative` instance because it require that given type has a [`Plus`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-control/4.0.0/docs/Control.Plus#t:Plus) instance:

```
The Plus type class extends the Alt type class with a value that should be the left and right identity for (<|>)

(...)

Members:

empty :: forall a. f a
```

I think that it is impossible to find any good candidate for an `empty` (where `empty :: ∀ a. f a`) value when we have only one constructor `Identity ∷ ∀ a. a → Identity a`.

For example in case of `Maybe` we have `empty = Nothing` and `<|>` with this value always gives `Nothing`.

> Which I don't understand why MonadZero would not work in this context, but regardless, I attempted to derive the Identity for MonadZero with things like this:
>
> ```hs
> newtype Identity a = Identity a
> derive instance newtypeIdentity :: Newtype (Identity a) _
> derive newtype instance monadZeroIdentity :: MonadZero Identity
> ```

When you are using newtype deriving you are telling the compiler that instance for your `newtype` should use "inner type" instance as an implementation. In this case you have only `a` type parameter and there is no "underlyning" instance at hand.

I think that if you want to use such a deriving you have to use concrete type which instances you want to use. For example here we are deriving `Functor` for our type `MaybeWrapper` which uses `Maybe` instance to provide appropriate members implementation (`map` in this case):

```hs
newtype MaybeWrapper a = MaybeWrapper (Maybe a)
derive instance newtypeMaybeWrapper :: Newtype (MaybeWrapper a) _
derive newtype instance functorMaybeWrapper :: Functor MaybeWrapper
```

Happy PureScript Hacking!

Comment: @superoven I think that it would be fair to give my answer some point as I've answered your question regarding `guard` directly and tackled all problems and spent some time on this...
Of course I've said that I understand that Fiodor answer tackles the merits and not the issues so it should be "accepted" one ;-)

Comment: It won't let me give you a point, I don't have enough reputation. Your answer did help me understand that I was looking at the problem wrong and how to dive deeper into how the monads work though.

Comment: @superoven, glad to hear that this answer was helpful in some way :-)